# Determine if NSString Holds a Value Other Than NULL/NIL

Tags: xcode, string, null

I'm trying to determine if the value of an NSString holds a value other than NULL/nil, and I'm not doing it correctly:

```
NSString *strWord;
strWord = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [someArray objectAtIndex:x]];

// THIS IS WRONG:

if (strWord != nil) {
    // do something
} else {
   // don't do something
}
```

Any help is appreciated!
lq

Comment: Why is this wrong? The check for != nil looks totally reasonable to me. You may want to set strWord = nil when you declare it.

Comment: @Stephen: Setting `strWord = nil` when declared won't do anything at all, because the value will be immediately overwritten with the results of `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]`

Comment: You are creating an NSString by calling `+stringWithFormat:`. It will never return nil. What do you intend to test for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is `strWord` actually contains `@"(null)"`, which is what happens if you pass `nil` to a `%@` format token in `+stringWithFormat:`. Instead you want to check if `[someArray objectAtIndex:x]` is `nil`. Luckily for you, there's a shortcut. Just use this instead:

```
NSString *strWord = [[someArray objectAtIndex:x] description];
```

This is identical to `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [someArray objectAtIndex:x]]` except if `[someArray objectAtIndex:x]` is `nil` then `strWord` will contain `nil` instead of `@"(null)"`. The reason for this is the `%@` format token simply calls `-description` on the passed argument, except it special-cases `nil` and turns it into `@"(null)"`. However, calling `-description` on the object directly will skip the `nil` check and simply return `nil` if called on `nil`.

Comment: Yes, it was returning @"(null)" but I couldn't figure out a way to check for the @"(null)" value since this doesn't work: if (strWord != null)... Thanks much!

Comment: Sorry to report that using: NSString *strWord = [[someArray objectAtIndex:x] description]; still contains (null) and is passing through the: if (strWord != nil) check.

Comment: That would imply that `[someArray objectAtIndex:x]` itself is returning `@"(null)"`. Either that, or `strWord` actually has `@"<null>"`, which implies you have `[NSNull null]` instead. You should take a look at precisely what `[someArray objectAtIndex:x]` is returning.

Comment: I solved this problem by preventing a nil value from being inserted into the array in the first place. Unfortunately this required constructing a third array in my scheme.

Answer (score 1):

@Kevin Ballard's technique is useful, but remember that `[someArray objectAtIndex:x]` can't return nil unless `someArray` is nil (you can't put nil in an `NSArray`). The closest it can return is `+[NSNull null]`, which is not the same thing. So if you're getting "(null)" here, that suggests that your array is actually nil. I'd probably check for that earlier in your method, rather than looking for the special case of @"(null)" in the string.